# space and time optimized algorithm for finding rows and columns with atleast single '1'

Tags: algorithm

For a given  matrix NxN having 0 or 1′s  only. find the count of rows and columns where at least one 1 occurs.

e,g

0 0 0 0

1 0 0 1

1 0 0 1

1 1 0 1

Row count having 1 at least once: 3

Col count having 1 at least once: 3

Mind is frozen can not think of any way better than normal double for loops giving me O(n^2) 
looking forward to some help

Comment: Are you expected to do better than a full scan?

Comment: Wouldn't that just be a O(2n) solution if you walked each number twice? How do you get n2?

Comment: i was looping through the rows(first loop for i) and then the columns(second loop for j) there by travelling by every element(a[i][j]) - which is not space and time optimized and thats why i need help in cracking it!

Comment: So in the worst case you will HAVE to go through each element, but by putting in checks ,whether you can exit early from a row scan.. So worst case time cannot be improved. imho.

Comment: the O(n2) is mistake so edit to O(n^2)

Comment: @smk - I would say worst case time cannot be improved *without altering the current data structure*, which could then increase the space complexity, and/or increase the time complexity of other operations.

Comment: @user986430 - It depends on the situation.  How many rows/columns can you expect to have?  Is "finding the rows/columns with a 1" the most common operation, or is it rare compared to inserts/updates/deletes, etc.?  My guess is that the interviewer would be at least as interested in the questions you ask as the solution you come up with.

Comment: This question is not precisely answerable without knowing how the matrix is stored. For example, if N caps out at 64 bits, you could store it in eight 8-byte integers and have fun with bitwise operations. If it's stored like a sparse matrix the algorithm could be O(N). If it's stored in a more bizarre format it could even be O(1).

Comment: @kaganar that's a nice thought , could u tell me how would the bit based solution work

Answer (score 1):

this solution prove you can not read your matrix less than O(N^2) but if your mean of this questions is you want to calculate your result in a search: I think it is not relation between do it or said that i need to solve this question in better order than O(2*(n^2)).

you need to Know about every cell in your array.assume you have a graph that every vertex is pointing to a cell in your matrix.for find about value of a cell you should search in your graph.you can do it with DFS in minimal order.

> The time and space analysis of [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) differs according to its
>   application area. In theoretical computer science, DFS is typically
>   used to traverse an entire graph, and takes time O(|E|), linear in the
>   size of the graph. In these applications it also uses space O(|V|) in
>   the worst case to store the stack of vertices on the current search
>   path as well as the set of already-visited vertices. Thus, in this
>   setting, the time and space bounds are the same as for breadth-first
>   search and the choice of which of these two algorithms to use depends
>   less on their complexity and more on the different properties of the
>   vertex orderings the two algorithms produce.

and you have N^2 vertex in your graph--array At least (O(V+E) >= O(V)). so you can not do it in better than O(n^2) with use every data-structure.(because calculate this order is not related to edge-structure).

```
maxcol=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  sumcol=0;
  for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
  {
    if (a[i][j]==1)
     {
       sumcol=sumcal+1;
     }  
  }
  if (sumcol>maxcol)
   {
     maxcol=sumcol;
   }
}
```

repeat this for rows.this is very easy solution but this code have a minimum space.and you can not improve it with algorithm idea.you should attention to means of algorithm complexity.you can solve it with one search but you just increase complexity  of your code.

Comment: It's trivial to do it better than O(n^2) - loop once through, column first, add rows. Loop again through, row first, add columns.

Comment: @ twanos aren't u looping N*N times ... how is the solution better than simple i-loop and j-loop solution

Comment: @amink since the enteries is all 1's and 0's can we do any bit operations as they as faster

Answer (score 0):

Idea: store the sum of numbers for each row and column in the matrix.

Additional storage: O(n * log(n)) - assuming O(log(n)) bits to store one number.

Time required to count the nonzero rows and columns: O(n).

This is a time-optimized algorithm, not a "space and time optimized algorithm" - it requires more space but less time.

Comment: @ anatolyg thanks for the solution even I had thought of the same thing but the problem I faced is that to find the sum for each col and row again I would need to traverse every element hence loop 2 times ( the i-th loop and the j-th loop) and additional array for sum and additional computation to look through the sum array - didnt seem to give me a good space and time optimized solution .... What do u say ?